# Cannot send a request with "http" in Angular

Tags: angular, api, http

I am trying to send a request to a WebApi but the "http" word gives an error saying "Property 'http' does not exist on type 'ProductComponent'"

here is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

interface Product {
  description: string;
  courseListIcon: string;
  iconUrl: string;
  longDescription: string;
  url: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  public urlParameter: string;
  public product: Object; //Product

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.urlParameter = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("urun");
    console.log(this.urlParameter);

    this.product = this.http.get<Product>("url");      // this line gives the error ***********
  }

}
```

Am I missing an import here? Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the `HTTPClient` to your component class.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private: http: HTTPClient) { 

}
```